# How do I get data out of a Uint8Array in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I am getting a MIDI message from a midiAccess object as an Uint8Array in a ClojureScript site but I can't seem to convert it to something I can get values from. `(js/console.log message)` generates `Uint8Array(3) [128, 65, 0]` in the browser console.
Actually, 'first' on the message gets the first value, but then 'second' does not. Using js->clj doesn't seem to convert it into anything usable. How do I wrangle the data out of it? I tried `js->clj` but that seemed to keep it the same.

Comment: UPDATE: tried nth, and get ```nth not supported on this type function Uint8Array()```

Comment: UPDATE2: well, apparently, I can ```(clojure.string/split message ",")``` and this gives me a vector I can access. I'm leaving the question here though in case any one has a brighter approach.

Comment: Just by curiosity, have you try a `aget` on it? Like `(aget message 0)`.

Comment: ```aget``` works a treat!

Comment: UPDATE3: well, haha, the ```clojure.string/split``` was *not* how it was working out... apparently I had coerced the message with ```(vec message)``` and then used ```nth``` on it. Seems like there are a lot of ways to make this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples:

```
(let [ui8a (Uint8Array.from [0 1 2 3 4 5])]
```

then

```
ui8a              => #object[Uint8Array 0,1,2,3,4,5]

(.-length ui8a)   => 6
(first ui8a)      => 0
(second ui8a)     => 1
(aget ui8a 3)     => 3

(into [] ui8a)    => [0 1 2 3 4 5]  ; either one works
(vec ui8a)        => [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

You may find this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) helpful.  Be especially sure to study the Clojure CheatSheet daily!

Comment: These all work, and thank you! I particularly am grateful for how all of them are so simple.

Comment: Note that you should probably stick to all the "a" functions as they are meant to work on arrays (eg. `aget`, `aset`, `alength`, etc). Depending on what kind of data you are dealing with it may be rather expensive to go to a vector first.